# Outlook body with clickable link?

Tags: python, outlook

I have the excel file with some url rows.
I want to copy excel table to Outlook body with clickable links of URL column, but when using this code, the url is copies to email without clickable.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Article.xlsx', index_col=False)
body = df.to_html()
outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'abc@example.com'
mail.Subject = "Test";
mail.HTMLBody = (body)
mail.Save()
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7AJy8YyD0--w6gy5aX5RdiuLL-dlETG/view?usp=sharing

I put my excel file on gg drive as below link.
Could you help me with this case? Thanks a lot.